# Rewriting to avoid the use of Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was trying to follow the tutorials found on: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-phpwikipedia/index.html

All tutorials use Zend framework. I was wondering how this code can be adapted to avoid the use of Zend (or any other prerequisites) if possible? Please see example below. Thanks.

```
<?php
// load Zend classes
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Rest_Client');

// define category prefix
$prefix = 'hollywood';

try {
// initialize REST client
$wikipedia = new Zend_Rest_Client('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php');

// set query parameters
$wikipedia->action('query');
$wikipedia->list('allcategories');
$wikipedia->acprefix($prefix);
$wikipedia->format('xml');

// perform request
// iterate over XML result set
$result = $wikipedia->get();
} catch (Exception $e) {
die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h2>Search results for categories starting with 
  '<?php echo $prefix; ?>'</h2>
<ol>
<?php foreach ($result->query->allcategories->c as $c): ?>
  <li><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:
    <?php echo $c; ?>"><?php echo $c; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$prefix = 'allcategories';
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list={$prefix}&format=json&continue=";
$res = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($res);
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h2>Search results for categories starting with 
  '<?php echo $prefix; ?>'</h2>
<ol>
<?php foreach ($data->query->allcategories as $c): 
?>
  <li><a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:<?php echo $c->{'*'}; ?>"><?php echo $c->{'*'}; ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case request will be using json format, its easier to live with :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the assist @FDIM but sorry this is not working in the format that is displayed above as no object was created.

Comment: I've updated the answer @Oroku, this time it's tested.

Answer (score 0):

As the IBM article mentions, the Wiki API by default returns results in `XML` but can also return results in `JSON`, `WDDX`, `YAML`, or `PHP serialized`.

Basically, you just need to make an `HTTP request` that requests the correct information and parses the returned results. For example click this link http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allcategories&acprop=size%20&acprefix=hollywood&format=xml and you see it returns `XML` results in the browser which you can pretty much use any language to loop over and parse.

To request the contents of the xml data in `PHP` you could use something `file_get_contents($target_url);` and then you wouldn't have to rely on creating a zend rest client.